# In a django template I would like to use the for loop.counter0 to index into a list

Tags: django, templates

I have something like the following:

```
{% for i in "xxxxxxxxx" %}
...
{% if passedInList.*forloop.counter0|add:"1"* %} Do Something {% endif %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously the if statement is incorrect. I have been using this method to create index names in forms for quite some time, but have never had to use the for loop counter index in an if statement.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `with` statement to save the forloop counter in a context variable, like so:

```
{% with index=forloop.counter %}
  {% if passedInList.index %} do something {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

(Also, seems like you can use `forloop.counter` instead of `forloop.counter0|add:"1"`)

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this does not seem to work. I have played around with this a bit and have printed the index to verify it is working, however the syntax "list.index" does not work. I have hard coded to ensure the list is being passed in correctly...